# How do use cut/paste shortcuts in selenium webdriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, shortcut

I'm using Selenium Webdriver and C# to write an automated test that will test that the keyboard shortcuts work on our app. This works for copy/paste:

```
public static void CopyPasteShortcut(string copyFrom, string pasteTo, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        Common.Helpers.ClickOn(copyFrom, driver);
        Actions copy = new Actions(driver);
        copy.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("c").KeyUp(Keys.Control);
        copy.Perform();

        Common.Helpers.ClickOn(pasteTo, driver); 
        Actions paste = new Actions(driver);
        paste.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("v").KeyUp(Keys.Control);
        paste.Perform();
    }
```

so why doesn't this work for cut/paste?

```
public static void CutPasteShortcut(string cutFrom, string pasteTo, IWebDriver driver)
    {
        Common.Helpers.ClickOn(cutFrom, driver);
        Actions cut = new Actions(driver);
        cut.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("x").KeyUp(Keys.Control);
        cut.Perform();

        Common.Helpers.ClickOn(pasteTo, driver);
        Actions paste = new Actions(driver);
        paste.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("v").KeyUp(Keys.Control);
        paste.Perform();
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure that the `cutFrom` element can be modified?  Only a very few can be (_e.g._, `<input type="text"/>`).

Comment: I figured it out.. it does work. I was missing a dot in my css selector, of course. Hope this will help anybody else hung up on keyboard shortcuts though.

Comment: I have a different problem too. When I say paste, it pastes in pairs. For example, when I say paste the word "yakup", it writes "yakup yakup".

Answer (score -1):

You forget the `.build()` before the `.perform()`. Tell me what's up.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, because it's not a *terrible* answer, but two things: 1) that is Java code you have, not C# and 2) In all the bindings, C# included, the `.perform()`/`.Perform()`, will do a `.build()`/`.Build()` for you, under the covers. So it's not the solution I'm afraid.

Comment: @Arran I though that Selenium worked the "same" in each language. My bad then.

Comment: Afraid not, see here, the current Java source: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java#355